# What is the best beetween multiple small h5 files or one huge?

Tags: multithreading, bigdata, h5py

I'm working with huge sattelite data that i'm splitting into small tiles to feed a deep learning model. I'm using pytorch, which means the data loader can work with multiple thread. 
[settings : python, Ubuntu 18.04]

I can't find any answer of which is the best in term of data accessing and storage between :

1. registering all the data in one huge HDF5 file (over 20Go)
2. splitting it into multiple (over 16 000) small HDF5 files (approx
       1.4Mo).

Is there any problem of multiple access of one file by multiple thread ? and in the other case is there an impact of having that amount of files ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for multiple files if I were you (but read till the end).

Intuitively, you could load at least some files into memory speeding the process a little bit (it is unlikely you would able to do so with 20GB, if you are, than you definitely should as RAM access is much faster).

You could cache those examples (inside custom `torch.utils.data.Dataset` instance) during the first past and retrieve cached examples (say in `list` or other more memory-efficient data structure with better cache-locality preferably) instead of reading from disk (similar approach to the one in Tensorflow's `tf.data.Dataset` object and it's `cache` method).

On the other hand, this approach is more cumbersome and harder to implement correctly,
though if you are **only reading** the file with multiple threads you should be fine and there shouldn't be any locks on this operation.

Remember to measure your approach with pytorch's profiler ([`torch.utils.bottleneck`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/bottleneck.html)) to pinpoint exact problems and verify solutions.

Comment: thanks for these advices ! I've gone for multiple files, i will see with the bottleneck where is the critical point